# MIPS program that reads a string of exactly 10 characters from user input

Tags: assembly, mips, radix, qtspim

> You will write a MIPS program that reads a string of exactly 10
> characters (including spaces, excluding the null character at the end)
> from user input.
>
> - For each of the characters in the input,
> - If it is from'0'to'9'and from'a'to β and from 'A'to Δ,treat it as a single digit base-N number. β stands for the M-th lower case letter
>   and Δ stands for the M-th upper case letter in the English alphabet.
>   In a base-N number, both 'a' and 'A' correspond to the decimal integer
>   of 10, both 'b' and 'B' to 11, and so on. Both β and Δ correspond to N
>   –1    If it is not in the aboves pecified range,ignore it.
> - Sum up all the single-digit base-N numbers from the input, multiply it by N, then print the result as an unsigned decimal number. If there
>   are no base-N numbers in the input, print 0

I get the following error in qtsim:

`spim: (parser) syntax error on line 69 of file /Users/.../Documents/GitHub/project1.s/proj1.asm              subi $t6, $t6, 32`

Here is my code:

```
.data
    prompt: .asciiz "Input: "
    N: .word 7
    M: .word 33
    END: .word 87
    newline: .asciiz "\n"
    output: .asciiz "Output: "
    userInput: .space 10 #only 10 characters allowed
.text
    main:
        #load useful values into appropriate registers
        lw $t5, N #load N into register t5
        lw $t4, END #load number END into t4 (last letter acceptable within range)
        la $s2, newline
        la $s3, output
        #prompt user to enter string
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, prompt
        syscall
        
        #get user input
        li $v0, 8
        la $a0, userInput #store input
        li $a1, 11 #max length of string
        syscall
        
        addi $t1, $zero, 0 #clear t1 register
        addi $t3, $zero, 0 #clear t3 register
        la $t2, userInput #load array into $t1
        
        while:
           beq $t1, 10, end #exit the loop if array end is reached
           
           lbu $t6, ($t2) #load byte from array
           
           ##manipulate character
           #Check if ascii is btn 48 and 57 (0-9)
           #subtract 48 from number if true and add result to totals register
           bge $t6, 48, check_number
           blt $t6, 48, skip
           check_number:
               ble $t6, 57, convert_0_9
               bgt $t6, 57, check_A_Delta
               
           check_A_Delta:
               blt $t6, 65, skip #skip if less than A
               bge $t6, 65, check_letter_limit
               
           check_letter_limit: #check if range is [A to A+(N-1)]. if not check if lower case letter
           #if range criteria is met convert letter to range [10 to (N-1)]
               bgt $t6, $t4, check_a_beta
               ble $t6, $t4, convert_letter
               
           check_a_beta:
           #check if letter >= 97. If not, ignore letter
           #if true convert to upper case and continue with formatting 
               blt $t6, 97, skip
               bge $t6, 97, convert_lower_to_upper
               
           convert_lower_to_upper:
           #check if letter > upper range limit. if so, skip
           #if within range, convert to upper case
              addi $s1, $zero, 119
              bgt $t6, $s1, skip
              ble $t6, $s1, lower_to_upper
              
          lower_to_upper:
          #convert lowercase to upper case and continue formatting
              subi $t6, $t6, 32
              j convert_letter
              
          convert_letter:
          #convert uppercase letter to range [10 to (N-1)]
              subi $t6, $t6, 55
              j add_to_total
          
          
          skip:
          
                  add $t1, $t1, 1
              addi $t2, $t2, 1 #increment array pointer
           
           
          j while
        end:
            mul $s0, $t3, $t5 #multiply sum with N and store in s0
            
            #print to see result
            li $v0, 4
            move $a0, $s2
            syscall
           
            li $v0, 4
            move $a0, $s3
            syscall
           
            li $v0, 36
            add $a0, $zero, $s0
            syscall
        
        #End of program
        li $v0, 10
        syscall
        
        
        convert_0_9: #change range (48-57) to (0-9)
            subi $t6, $t6, 48
            j add_to_total
                
        add_to_total:
            add $t3, $t3, $t6
            j skip
```

Comment: Not sure if that's what qtspim is complaining about, but MIPS doesn't have a `subi` instruction, though you can do `addi` of -32.

Comment: There's an approach described as minimal example to reproduce a problem; this is a good technique to know for the programming industry, and it is highly welcome here.  The idea is to cut the error down to the fewest number of lines and then share just that.

Comment: @ErikEidt To be fair, some assemblers do let you type `subi` and automatically change it to an `addi`. Although I could be thinking of `addiu` and `subiu`.

Comment: @puppydrum64, sure, MARS, for example, will accept `subi`, but not qtspim, even with pseudo instructions setting enabled.